# There are a "frictionless access" recomendarion for Web page requests?

Tags: classification

Transparency is "free access", frictionless. Even publishing in the Web, with no password required, we can imagine a gradation of  frictionless. [This access problem was posted at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/999208/439867):

1. With usual `.gov` pages (URLs) with full-free access, we can do `wget URL` or `curl -O URL`  to download the page. Is a real "access without barriers".
2. With some other pages (eg. [this one](http://www.planalto.gov.br/CCivil_03/leis/2002/L10406compilada.htm)), with the same  "free access needs", the behaviour is different, and we can't download.

There are a RFC (or W3C recommendation, or similar) suggesting or classifying whats is "HTTP frictionless access"?

---

PS: I need a standard that describes all the shades of gray between the "100% free and frictionless"  and the "non-free access"... or something defining a kind of "best practices for frictionless HTTP request/response".